# Cuántos meses demoraría en saldar su deuda en código sql

Tags: postgresql

Tengo la mañana entera tratando de solucionar esto y es que suponiendo que no puede pagar más de una cuota al mes. ¿Cuántos
meses demoraría en saldar su deuda? dada la consulta de esta tabla.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS finanzas_personales;

CREATE TABLE finanzas_personales
(
nombre character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
me_debe integer,
cuotas_cobrar integer,
le_debo integer,
cuotas_pagar integer,
CONSTRAINT finanzas_personales_pkey PRIMARY KEY (nombre)
);

insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('tía carmen', 0, 0, 5000, 1);
insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('papá', 0, 0, 15000, 3);
insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('nacho', 10000, 2, 7000, 1);
insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('almacén esquina', 0, 0, 13000, 2);
insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('vicios varios', 0, 0, 35000, 35);
insert into finanzas_personales (nombre, me_debe, cuotas_cobrar, le_debo, cuotas_pagar)
values ('compañero trabajo', 50000, 5, 0, 0);

select * from finanzas_personales ;
```

Estuve haciendo esto pero realmente no es lo que manda hacer

```
SELECT cuotas_pagar, now()
FROM finanzas_personales
```

Comment: La consulta es cuanto tiempo demoras en pagar **TU** deuda con cada persona? o Cuanto tiempo demorarán en pagarte a vos?

Comment: Si mi deudas suponiendo que no puede pagar más de una cuota al mes. ¿Cuántos
meses demoraría en saldar mi deuda?

Comment: Creo que la consulta sería `SELECT sum(cuotas_pagar) FROM finanzas_personales` En caso que puedas pagar 1 sola cuota por mes de todas las que tienes o `SELECT MAX(cuotas_pagar) FROM finanzas_personales` en caso que le puedas pagar una cuota a cada uno por mes.

Comment: @Liyo Muchas gracias es la respuesta que estaba buscando